# WCF host machine losing connections

Tags: c#, wcf

Really need some good solutions for the rare-headache problem I met.

The background is for meeting the client's requirement, I developed a FileTransfer wcf service  for transferring the files between internet and enterprise's intranet, so there I used a Windows Service to host it by providing two protocols, http and tcp, former for internet data transmiting and the latter for the intranet. But, unfortunately, the Windows Service host is in a hostile network condition, more specifically to say, it loses connections randomly.

For intention of transferring the large files, i set the sendtimout, receivetimeout, opentimeout and closetimeout to a relatively big value like "00:30:00", but sometimes if the connection was lost or unstable, it had to wait for a long time for a cycle of send-response.

Any ideas or tricky solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Folder" value="C:\Share\Test"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileTransferHttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864"
                 openTimeout="12:00:00" closeTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="12:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="FileTransferTcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="FileTransferServiceBehaviors" name="FileTransfer.FileTransferService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileTransferHttpBinding" contract="FileTransfer.IFileTransferService"/>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileTransferTcpBinding" contract="FileTransfer.IFileTransferService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8524/FileTransfer"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8525/FileTransfer"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FileTransferServiceBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: *But, unfortunately, the Windows Service host is in a hostile network condition, more specifically to say, it loses connections randomly.* Well configuring timeouts isn't going to help if the actual connection is dropped. Be tolerant to failure. Transfer the file in chunks.

Comment: Yes, it was sent in chunks like 100 * 1024 bytes per time, but I mean is there possible to because of the big timeout settings, once the connection was lost it has to wait long enough for getting a timeout error then automatically move to handle next chunk?

Comment: Maybe http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ff47898-508c-4965-a14b-893ae58e391f/keepalive-in-wcf